# Return all codes - String

Tags: c++, recursion

Assume that the value of a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ... , z = 26. You are given a numeric string S. Write a program to return the list of all possible codes that can be generated from the given string.

For most of the cases this code works but it gives wrong output for inputs which have numbers greater than 26. For eg: 12345.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


using namespace std;
int atoi(char a)
{
    int i=a-'0';
    return i;
}
char itoa(int i)
{
    char c='a'+i-1;
    return c;
}
int getCodes(string input, string output[10000]) {
   if(input.size()==0)
   {
       return 1;
   }
    if(input.size()==1)
    {
        output[0]=output[0]+itoa(atoi(input[0]));
        return 1;
    }
    string result1[10000],result2[10000];
    int size2;

    int size1=getCodes(input.substr(1),result1);
    if(input.size()>1)
    {
        if(atoi(input[0])*10+atoi(input[1])>10&&atoi(input[0])*10+atoi(input[1])<27)
        {
            size2=getCodes(input.substr(2),result2);
        }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
    {
        output[i]=itoa(atoi(input[0]))+result1[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size2;i++)
    {
        output[i+size1]=itoa(atoi(input[0])*10+atoi(input[1]))+result2[i];
    }
    return size1+size2;
}



int main(){
    string input;
    cin >> input;

    string output[10000];
    int count = getCodes(input, output);
    for(int i = 0; i < count && i < 10000; i++)
        cout << output[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if i give input 12345, the output is:
"
abcde
awde
lcde
l"
instead of :
"
abcde
awde
lcde"

Comment: My advice is to use an IDE with a debugger like Visual Studio so that you can step through your code 1 line at a time looking at your variables at each step to identify the place where your code deviates from your expectation.

Comment: `string output[10000];` I don't understand why you want an array of 10 thousand strings.

Comment: I also don't understand the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: okay look. for example i give you an input 1123. so you have to write a code such that the final output which gets printed is "aabc alc aaw kbc kw"

Comment: you have to print all the combinations that's it

Comment: What @priyansh is trying to accomplish is to group digits into numbers that are less than 26 and convert these groups to letters so in 12345 you have {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {12, 3, 4, 5} and {1, 23, 4, 5}, which, when substituted with letters, give you strings "abcde" "awde" and "lcde". Hope this helps as I don't have time to analyse that right now. Also don't allocate 10000 strings on the stack - use std::vector instead.

Comment: @Grabusz thank you. I think priyansh should add this description to the question. it makes the problem more clear.

Answer (score 2):

i got it fellow members. i did not initialised the size2 variable to zero. also i didn't use >= operator.

```
int getCodes(string input, string output[10000]) {
   if(input.size()==0)
   {
       output[0]="";
       return 1;
   }
    if(input.size()==1)
    {
        output[0]=itoa(atoi(input[0]));
        return 1;
    }
    string result1[10000],result2[10000];
    int size2=0;

    int size1=getCodes(input.substr(1),result1);
    if(input.size()>1)
    {
        if(atoi(input[0])*10+atoi(input[1])>=10&&atoi(input[0])*10+atoi(input[1])<27)
        {
            size2=getCodes(input.substr(2),result2);
        }

    }
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
    {
            output[k++]=itoa(atoi(input[0]))+result1[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size2;i++)
    {
            output[k++]=itoa(atoi(input[0])*10+atoi(input[1]))+result2[i];
    }
    return k;
}
```

this is the final code for getCodes function. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: The code from @jdehesa is very much better `c++` code than this. My advice is to study the code from the other answer.

Comment: Yes I agree @jdehesa has written much better code than me :) . But I find it necessary to let others know what mistake I did :) .

Answer (score 1):

You can do that more simply with something like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getCodesRec(unsigned int num, string& current, vector<string>& result)
{
    // First and last chars for the codes
    static constexpr char FIRST_CHAR = 'a';
    static constexpr char LAST_CHAR = 'z';
    if (num == 0)
    {
        // When there is no more number add the code to the results
        result.push_back(current);
    }
    else
    {
        // Add chars to the existing code
        unsigned int next = num;
        unsigned int rem = next % 10;
        unsigned int f = 1;
        // While we have not gone over the max char number
        // (in practice this loop will run twice at most for a-z letters)
        while (next > 0 && rem <= (unsigned int)(LAST_CHAR - FIRST_CHAR) + 1)
        {
            next = next / 10;
            if (rem != 0)  // 0 does not have a replacement
            {
                // Add the corresponding char
                current.insert(0, 1, FIRST_CHAR + char(rem - 1));
                // Recursive call
                getCodesRec(next, current, result);
                // Remove the char
                current.erase(0, 1);
            }
            // Add another number
            f *= 10;
            rem += f * (next % 10);
        }
    }
}

vector<string> getCodes(unsigned int num)
{
    vector<string> result;
    string current;
    getCodesRec(num, current, result);
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int num = 12345;
    vector<string> codes = getCodes(12345);
    cout << "Codes for " << num << endl;
    for (string& code : codes)
    {
        cout << "* " << code << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Codes for 12345
* abcde
* lcde
* awde
```

Comment: i got it fellow members. i did not initialised the size2 variable to zero. also i didn't use >= operator.